# Google Stackdriver Error Reporting blank (not set up)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

We are starting to enable Stackdriver for our project, but while I have a ubuntu instance with stackdriver logging, and I am getting the logs shipped back (I can see the logs in Stackdriver Logging), when I browse to Error Reporting, it's just a blank screen with a button to "Setup Error Reporting", which takes me to some API documentation which I think is tailored for new application coding.  We are running nginx and the logging is working, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the Error Reporting to work properly, if that's even doable.

Answer (score 2):

"Setup Error Reporting" should guide you to the setup documentation (not API documentation). Depending on the platform you are using, you might need to perform some changes in your application's code or log format. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/

If you have Stackdriver Logging setup and on Google Compute Engine, the requirement is for your exception stack traces to be log in single log entries.

Comment: Thanks, this is where I get confused.  We are using nginx, so I can't change the application code (well maybe I could, but i don't have the technical skills). It is logging to an error log though, and the logging agent is set up for it.    We do have Logging set up, but the Error Reporting page is blank.  So does that mean the error log is in the incorrect format?  How do I fix that?

Comment: If you are on Google Compute Engine and i the application prints exception stack traces, what you need to do is make sure all frame of a stack trace are stored in the [textPayload of a LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/reference/rest/v2/LogEntry). How do you send your logs to Stackdriver Logging? Using the fluentd agent? Do you use its default configuration?